# Recreational activities

Tags: vedas, upanishads, rishi

Can someone please provide the recreational activities suggested by ancient sages for students so that I can focus better. I mean how students in ancient India, while staying away from cities used to entertain themselves. At which time of the day they give for leisure activities and what were there leisure activities?